# socket.io verify token from every emit from client

Tags: authentication, socket.io

I'm using Firebase Authentication as the authentication service of my app.

While creating a live chat app with socket.io, I would like to authenticate every `socket.emit()` from the client to assure the data I'm processing over the server is valid.

Thus, in my `data (object)`  of every `socket.emit("newMsgFromClient",data)`, I will put a token in there so that server-side can verify the emit is from the legit user.

I would like to know is this the right practice or there is a better way to perform verification?

Comment: Why don't check it at the client connection ?

Comment: What do you mean check it at client connection?

Comment: Look at [the doc](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) and look at a word called 'payload'...